# Issues with finding the 0's in a matrix

Tags: excel, vba

I'm looking at a spreadsheet in excel

```
Name   |    Paperwork     |    Paperwork 1     | Paperwork 2
Joe    |        1         |      1             |   1 
Jane   |        0         |      1             |   0
```

I'm trying to find the 0 in the spreadsheet, and output something like
There is an error in the Paperwork assigned to Jane for Paperwork 2

The VBA code I have is:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, Staff As String, Consumer As String, Error As String, CurCell As String

MsgBox "Starting the routine..."
For i = 2 To 3
    If Cells(i, 2).Value = 0 Then

        For j = 3 To 4
          If Cells(i, j).Value = 1 Then
             CurCell = i & ", " & j

        Else
             CurCell = i & ", " & j
             MsgBox CurCell


     End If
     Next j
     End If
     Next i


End Sub
```

I'm trying to scan paperwork; its a column that says whether the paperwork is completed. Because Joe completed his paperwork, the algorithm moves past it. Jane however is missing paperwork 2. So when the algorithm arrives at position (Jane, Paperwork) it begins to look in row (paperwork)

For (Jane, Paperwork 1) the algorithm sees a 1, and moves to increment
For (Jane, Paperwork 2) the algorithm sees a 0, and what I want to do is display:
"Jane is missing" + Paperwork 2.

I would like to do something at that point like setting the Staff string variable to be = Cell(row i, j).value, and then outputting 'Staff' to somewhere on the spreadsheet, but I don't know the VBA syntax to be able to do so.

Comment: May I just ask why the use of VBA over a formula?

Comment: Please [edit] your question title to something that is more descriptive of the problem you're having or the question you're asking. *Excel-VBA* is information available in the tags, and removing it from the title leaves *Issues with*, which provides no information. In addition, question titles should convey information that will have meaning to future users of this site who find it in a search results list. Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `.Find` to find the `0` values instead of looping through cells? See [This](http://www.siddharthrout.com/2011/07/14/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/)

Comment: @chancea I have tried this with a pretty intensive index/small formula. I don't like it, but it works, it's very clumsy though and pretty easily going to fail imo. siddarth I'm not anywhere close to using 65000 cells of data

Comment: @user3097236 Well _personally_ I would stick with a formula.  I feel there is the same if not more of a chance of an error going to happen with VBA than with built in formulas.  Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Sub ZeroError()
Dim rng As Range

Dim rowREF As Integer    'row reference
Dim colREF As Integer   ' column reference
Dim eName As String 'name holder for employee
Dim wAssignment As String 'assignment holder e.g. Paperwork
Dim colLOCATION As Integer ' this is the column you want to put your results in
colLOCATION = 1 ' placing everying in column note that i add 6 in CELLS
rowREF = 1
colREF = 1

eName = ""
wAssignment = ""

Set rng = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

For Each cell In rng




    If cell.Value = 0 Then
        rowREF = cell.Row

                    colREF = cell.Column
                    eName = Cells(rowREF, 1)
                    wAssignment = Cells(1, colREF)

            If (eName <> "" And wAssignment <> "") Then
                        If Cells(rowREF, colLOCATION + 6) <> "" Then
                            colLOCATION = colLOCATION + 1
                        Else
                            colLOCATION = 1
                        End If
                Cells(rowREF, colLOCATION + 6) = eName & " " & "is missing" & " " & wAssignment
            End If

    End If

    If cell.Value <> 0 Then
        rowREF = cell.Row

                    colREF = cell.Column
                    eName = Cells(rowREF, 1)
                    wAssignment = Cells(1, colREF)

        If (eName <> "" And wAssignment <> "") Then
                        If Cells(rowREF, colLOCATION + 6) <> "" Then
                            colLOCATION = colLOCATION + 1
                        Else
                            colLOCATION = 1
                        End If

        Cells(rowREF, colLOCATION + 6) = eName & " " & "has completed" & " " & wAssignment
        End If
    End If
    Debug.Print colLOCATION
Next
End Sub
```

Adjusted to your settings in the below answer - sorry I am not the most efficient coder but it should work out for you.

Comment: Ok. I have a matrix of 54 rows and 11 columns, meaning 594 cells. Each cell contains either a 1 or a 0. I want to find which cell contains a 0, and output to another location which row its in and which column its in. I'm interested in outputting the row or column's name - meaning if its in row 30 column 5, I'm interested in the name of that column and the name of that row. The name of the column would be located in the 1st row; the name of the row would be located in the 1st column.

Comment: in the case of the above range, I'm not interested in outputting the address of the row (3,4) but rather the names associated with it (jane, paperwork2)

Comment: If cell.Value = 0 Then MsgBox "There is an Error in your WorkSheet at Address:" & " " & cell.Address Exit Sub End If

Comment: as everyone else in this thread stated you are better off using an excel function `=if(B2= 0, concatenate(A1, " is missing work assignment", B$1), concatenate(A1, " has completed work assignment", B$1))` Populate that across the cells the cell reference is RELATIVE.

Answer (score 0):

Using the `.CurrentRegion` as a starting point, you should be able to offset and loop through each of the numbered cells. I've put the results into an unused column to the right. this is the best that I could figure out from your narrative.

```
Sub lost_Paperwork()
    Dim iStaffCol As Long, rng As Range
    With ActiveSheet        'define this worksheet peoperly!
        With .Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
            iStaffCol = .Columns.Count + 2
            For Each rng In .Offset(1, 1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1, .Columns.Count - 1)
                If rng.Value = 0 Then _
                    .Cells(Rows.Count, iStaffCol).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0) = _
                      .Cells(rng.Row, 1).Value & ", missing " & .Cells(1, rng.Column).Value
            Next rng
        End With
        .Cells(1, iStaffCol) = "Staff"
    End With
End Sub
```

Your results should resemble the following.

[image]

Comment: Hi Jeeped thanks for the answer.
The only issue that I see from the narrative is that Joe is not missing anything, so I don't see why in column F2 there would be something "Jane, missing Paperwork". It should say something like "Completed".